# Garage door lock broken

Tags: lock, garage-door

The internal side of my garage door lock is broken (first image). Due to this, the cable that pulls the latch is no longer pulling it and hence the garage door cannot be opened (third image). I could not find an exact replacement online or in stores near me for the broken part. What would be the easiest way to have this fixed?

[image: inner side of the lock]
[image: outer side of the lock]
[image: latch that prevents door to open after broken]

Comment: Just buy a whole new lock, most of them work the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just go and buy a whole new lock.  Trying to repair them by buying pieces, usually cost about the same.

Most garage door locks work the same way, by moving a cable.

Most locks should fit in the same hole as the old lock, even if they look a bit different.

The one I have, has the cable sliding the catches into holes in the track.  Quite sure yours or mine can be replaced with each other.

Comment: The handle mechanism twists to pull on a cable. It doesn't really matter if the other end of the cable is attached to a hinged mechanism like this or a sliding bolt. So long as it pulls the cable, the other end will be actuated. The only twist might be in readjusting the length of the cable if the replacement plate is a different size/has holes in a different place. Shouldn't need to be an _exact_ length, just good enough to cause it to work.

Comment: Bought similar product on Amazon and replaced it. It was an easy install.

Garage Door Lock-Inside Release Handle- Black Plastic Direct Replacement https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07H3JG6SJ

Answer (score 2):

Find a metal bracket or piece of steel, drill where the holes are, and either pop-rivet, bolt, or best, weld it onto the existing broken bracket. Might even get away with welding the broken bit back in place, but it looks flimsy to me. Mine was the same - designed so that it would break if someone forced the outside handle trying to gain entry when it was locked. Which actually happened.

With easy access from inside, I also drilled through the runners, so a bolt (or padlock) could be inserted from inside the garage, to stop the door being lifted with a lever - the rollers would just jam.

Answer (score 0):

Bought similar product on Amazon and replaced it. It was an easy install.

Garage Door Lock-Inside Release Handle- Black Plastic Direct Replacement https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07H3JG6SJ

Comment: Self-answering a question is great. Answering it by stating that you did what others recommended, then giving your answer the check-mark (accepting it as the "correct" answer) is... tacky. How about giving credit (up votes) to those who provided you with help, then selecting one of the "buy a replacement" answers as the "correct" one, since you probably wouldn't have taken this action without their advice.